# php preg_replace return first match when use (.*) in middle

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some code like this:

```
$string = "background: #FFFFFF url('http://www.zxczxc.com/asd.jpg') 20px 100px no-repeat";
$value  = preg_replace('/background: (.*)? ([0-9\.]+)([a-z\%]+)?/', '$2', $string);
```

How can I get `preg_replace` to return `20px` instead of `100px`?

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: i expect to return 20px

Comment: you want to return or replace?

Comment: @chris85 you solve my problem :)

i can now  handle 0 or negative pixel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(.*)?` is inverted of what you intended the `?` needs to be inside otherwise the search is greedy, but optional. You also need an optional leading `-` incase the pixels are negative.

```
$value  = preg_replace('/background: (.*?) (-?[0-9\.]+)([a-z\%]+)?/','$2',$string);
```

Comment: Little compensation for your trouble ;-) no rabbit hole here.